# Sharing property data between sister components in vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components Header.vue and Sidebar.vue

On Header.vue i have a button which onclick i need to change the value of property in Sidebar.vue

On Header.vue i have

template:

```
<a v-on:click="toggleSidebar">Toggle</a>
```

method:

```
toggleNavbar: function() {
      this.toggleSidebar(this.showSidebar)
    }
```

On Sidebar.vue
template:

```
<div class="sidebar sidebar_display_none" :class="showSidebar?'show':''">
```

Method:

```
 created() {
    this.showSidebar= this.toggleSidebar(this.showSidebar)
    console.log(this.showSidebar)
  }
```

On Mixin

```
toggleSidebar: function(currentState) {
            return  !currentState

        }
```

Onclick Toggle button i need to show/hide Sidebar (showSidebar property is boolean)

How can i do it? Thanks

Comment: You need to define `showSidebar`. Is it defined anywhere ?

Comment: Yes. I defined it inside data on SIdebar.vue

Comment: But you are also accessing it in Header.vue ? You need to define it there as well.

Comment: It seems you need to share state between two components.You might want to take a look at vuex.

Answer (score 0):

Psidom's comment above of studying [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) is spot on. In addition, you should look into [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) and [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event) as another resource/skill for sharing and managing data between components.

*Note I would've loved to have left this as a comment as well but I don't have the reputation for comments yet...*